# Tomcat server doGet function works but not respond to web browser

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets

guys. I've been stuck to this for couple of hours and it's killing me.
I set up a very simple Tomcat v7.0 server with Eclipse. I create a servlet to do some test.
My web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>AuthServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>MyServlet.AuthServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AuthServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And AuthServlet looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("doGet------");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
        if (name.equals("wei") && pwd.equals("123456")) {
            System.out.println("success-------");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>test</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<p>Both username and password are correct</p>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
            out.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("failed-------");
            //show wrong message
        }
    }
```

And then I put *http://192.168.1.102:8080/WebappName/demo?username=xxx&password=xxx* into the web browser and give it a go, I can see the Console of Eclipse printing *doGet------*,*success-------*,but the browser just loading and after a while, it just blank. I use the browser's console to see what was going on, and I got this:

```
NS_ERROR_HOST_IS_IP_ADDRESS: Component returned failure code: 0x804b0051 (NS_ERROR_HOST_IS_IP_ADDRESS) [nsIEffectiveTLDService.getBaseDomain]
```

I didn't figure this out and I need some help,thank you advance.

Comment: in netbeans works like a charm, did you try with complete hostname instead of the ip address? please note that using  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8") makes the previous line response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") useless

Comment: Try to use `response.flushBuffer()` instead of `out.close()` - servlet container should close the `out` writer on his own.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply. I somehow solved it by changing to another Wifi. Seemed something wrong with the IP address 192.168.1.102, I just can't get it to work. As soon as I changed my Wifi to another Router, everything is OK. Still,I don't know why. Thank you @jsfviky for your note.

Comment: Thank you @JozefChocholacek for your help. I'll look into what you said.